# Remove white corners on the embedded YouTube Subscribe button?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

[image: Image of Subscribe button]

When I embed a subscribe button to my webpage, there are some weird white corners, even if i use the dark theme option. Any Ideas how to fix that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be:

- *On your style sheet*, apply a CSS declaration for set a background color *equals* to your webpage's color.

Example (*keep in mind this is an example, your style may vary*):

```
/* "divContainer" is the name of the class that contains your image. */
.divContainer { 
    background: #4a4e51; /* Add here the same color as your webpage. */
}
```

I tested this code here on Stack Overflow, because I also observe white corners on my profile picture *and I'm using the dark theme*.

The code I used for test here the fix is as follows:

```
.s-avatar.s-avatar__24 {
    width: var(--su-static24);
    height: var(--su-static24);
    background: #4a4e51; /* Set the same background color of Stack Overflow. */
}
```